# What is written in this old handwritten French text?

Tags: traduction

I found this old mary / pieta print and it had this old French text on the back. I'm wondering what it means and since the handwriting is challenging to transcribe it'd be great to get feedback on it. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La retranscription du texte de votre image est la suivante :

> En hommage de très vive reconnaissance 
>   de la part de la paroisse St Antoine à 
>   Charleroi (Ville-Basse) pour le pieux 
>   et admirable dévouement de Monsieur et 
>   Madame Braeckman. 
>   Que Notre-Dame au Rempart de Charleroi 
>   les protège. 
>   Le curé les bénit de tout cœur.

Le message est signé « H. Bahat » et est daté du 26 octobre 48.

En anglais, il pourrait être traduit ainsi :

> As a token of very deep gratitude from the parish of Saint-Antoine in Charleroi (Ville-Basse) for the pious and admirable devotion of Mr. and Mrs. Braeckman. 
>   May Our Lady in Rempart of Charleroi protect them. 
>   The priest wholeheartedly blesses both of them.

Je remercie [Eau qui dort](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/7738/eau-qui-dort) et [jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/1109/jlliagre) pour leur commentaire éclairé !

Comment: hommage **et** très vive. Pour le **pieux** et admirable. Et c'est Braeckman, not Brouchmon (nom flamand). La signature lit h. Ba?? (Bahot ?)

Comment: @Eauquidort Effectivement, c'est bien vu pour l'adjectif « pieux ». En revanche, j'ai encore des doutes sur la première ligne. J'ai l'impression de voir le mot « de » plutôt que « et », mais dans tous les cas, ça ne signifie pas grand chose…

Comment: « En hommage *de* très vive reconnaissance » = *as a token of very deep gratitude* est la seule interprétation possible, vu la similitude avec les deux autres occurrences de « de » et au contraire la grande différence avec les deux « et ». De plus, la formule « hommage de reconnaissance » se rencontre relativement fréquemment entre 1800 et 1960. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hommage+de+reconnaissance&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=1

Comment: @jlliagre Je te remercie pour tes précisions ! C'est une formule qui m'était tout à fait inconnue.

Comment: Je ne suis pas un expert capable de dater le papier peint en fond, mais il me semble que la date pourrait également être 1848, voir 1748. Peut être faudrait-il laisser 48, dans le doute ?

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas C'est exact, j'ai édité ma réponse en conséquence.

Comment: So, translation is allowed here?

Comment: @Lambie: The transcription is the main source of concern here. The day we get flooded with questions like that we will think about it again.

Comment: Je traduirais la dernière phrase *The priest wholeheartedly blesses (both of) them*.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est modifié ! J'étais décidément bien fatigué, hier !